# handle unicode strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, unicode

I have a unicoded string given to me and I have to convert it into string in javascript like this

```
u'course' ---> course
```

I have tried this

```
value = u'engineering'
var key = value.replace(/'/g, "").replace(/u/g,"").replace(' ','');
```

But this is returning me `corse` as the result. Also I dont want to achive this by string manipulation. Does javascript provide some function to handle unicoded string

Comment: What does "unicoded" mean? As long as the page encoding is UTF-8, javascript will handle unicode strings

Comment: @Ha11owed: JavaScript handles Unicode strings regardless. It's just a matter of making sure they're conveyed to JavaScript correctly (for instance, by encoding the page/script/whatever in UTF-8 or another encoding that preserves the information correctly).

Answer (score 0):

The `u'course'` syntax is in the Python code. If you convey that string to JavaScript in the normal way (in JavaScript it would be `"course"`), it will be handled correctly. JavaScript strings are intrinsically Unicode (*mostly*).

---

Why "mostly" above: JavaScript strings are a bit curious. Strings are stored in UTF-16, and each JavaScript string character maps to one UTF-16 word (16 bits). But in UTF-16, some characters don't fit in one word, they need two (32 bits). (This primarily occurs in far-east languages.) In JavaScript, that one actual Unicode character occupies two "characters" of the string, one for each word. This only becomes an issue if you do things with the string like `substring` and such, which could separate the two words of the character.